# Wordpress how to embed and view the pdf file using a custom code

Tags: wordpress

Is there's a way to view the pdf file post using a custom code?
Normally when we create a blog archives the permalink will direct to another page to view its full details. but this time my goal is to create an image archives that all links are PDF file using this wordpress code:

```html
<?php the_permalink(); ?>
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question correct, but I think this may be what your looking for [viewerjs](https://viewerjs.org/)

Comment: Hi @JasperB basically my goal is to attached the pdf file in normal Post using the Add Media Button with thumbnail picture, so once the Post is echoed on my frontend the pdf link open the file once the thumbnail image is clicked. I am using Wordpress-5.7.2 with custom theme

Comment: ah I see, maybe this [greengeeks.com tutorial](https://greengeeks.com/tutorials/article/how-to-generate-pdf-thumbnails-in-wordpress/) can help you